# what does としてもだ mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntax

> 千枝実に問いた限りでは、「宴」 は極めて危険で悪質な因習だ。
>   そういう昔話があったとして、過去には実際に私刑を行った歴史があった**としてもだ**、普通はもっと無難な祭りとかに形を変えて現代に伝わっているものだろう。

What is the purpose of the だ after the the highlighted としても in the second sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This だ is optional, but it works *like* a sentence-end/filler particle that adds an emphasis to the speaker's opinion. It's relatively masculine. This だ to emphasize ても/でも is uncommon in real-life conversations, but is sometimes found in novels/manga. It doesn't have to be translated, but its role is semantically similar to "you know", "well", "even" or italics/all-caps.

From 明鏡国語辞典 第二版:

> #### だ
>
> 〔終助詞的に〕 相手への訴えかけを強める。「そこで**だ**、きみは**だ**ね、あす出発してくれ」

Similar examples:

> - もしも**だ**、君が空を飛べるとしよう。
> - ところが**だ**よ、この話には続きがある。
> - つまり**だ**、君にこの仕事をお願いしたいんだ。
> - 本当は**だ**な、こんなことを言いたくないんだ。

ですよ/ですね/です is used in a similar manner (sounds politer):

> - もしも**です**、あなたが空を飛べるとしましょう。
> - ところが**ですね**、この話には続きがあるんです。
> - つまり**ですよ**、君にこの仕事をお願いしたいんです。
> - 本当は**ですね**、こんなことを言いたくないんです。