# Is ないとだ correct Japanese?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence, anime, construction

> A: めっちゃ好き　かっこよすぎ
> B: だね
> A:あッ　来週ドラマ出るし　見ないとだよ

From the context (them talking about a celebrity), I understood that "見ないとだ" is similar to "見ないといけない". But when I searched for it online, an user on https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/240162 said that it isn't correct Japanese. Is that the case, and if so, how common is it?

Comment: Looks like this dialog is from the anime movie *Koe no Katachi* (*A Silent Voice*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sentence is not formal, but it's not incorrect. Sometimes だ can be used as a sentence-end or interjectory particle, and だ/です can appear after ないと, なきゃ, かも, たら, etc.

- [Do certain particles behave like nouns? Case in point:「かも」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/85826/5010)
- [what does としてもだ mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58949/5010)
- [~たいだとか why is there a だ here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60014/5010)