# What does なるようになれだ mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, words, manga, sentence

[image]

The meaning of the sentence aside, I also wonder why だ is used at the end. Is it for emphasis or something like that?

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58949/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/87158/5010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also wonder why だ is used at the end.

It quotes the phrase 「なるようになれ」 as a noun referring to the policy "let it be". So to complement a context, it kind of says:

- I'll bet on "let it be".

Answer (score 2):

"なる" = "to be"
"ように" = "like"
"なれ" = "Be"

So it means something like "let it be" in a negative tone. He gets desperate.