# What is the meaning of で...だ!

Tags: meaning

Context, a guy apologizes to a girl

> A: 一瀬さっきは責めるようなこと言って悪かったな
> B: 何急に
> A: で...だ! 今度こそ一瀬の悩みを解説する料理ができたんだ。

Any idea of what it could mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

でだ is an emphasized "And then", "So" or "Well then".

- **で** is a conjunction meaning "and then". It's the same as それで. It can be used to change topics or go to a main topic, just as "So" or "Well" in English can.
- **だ** in this context is a kind of intensifier. See: [what does としてもだ mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58949/5010)