# Understanding その上で、だ

Tags: grammar, expressions, set-phrases

> 続いて、ライデンが名乗った。
>
> 「戦隊副長、ライデン・シュガだ。……まず最初に謝っとく。あんたが毎晩繫いでくるのを、俺達は聖女気取りの偽善者のブタが、自分のブタ加減に気づきもしねぇでおめでたいって笑ってた。それについては詫びる。悪かった。**その上で、だ**」
>
> 黒鉄色の双眸が冷然と細まる。
>
> 「セオが言ったとおり、俺達はあんたを対等とも仲間とも思わない。あんたは俺達を踏みつけた上で、上から綺麗事吹いてるアホだ。それはどうあろうと変わらないし、だからそうとしか見做さない。それでもいいっていうなら暇つぶしにこれまでどおり相手はしてやるが、個人的にはそれも勧めねぇ。あんたはハンドラーには向いてない。……辞めた方がいいぜ」

86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

I get that the speaker apologized to the addressee but didn’t treat the addressee equally.

My questions are:

1. Can we use その上 here? Both その上で and その上 mean "in addition to that", it appears. Or are there any difference between them?
2. What is the function of the だ? Why is it used alone there?

Comment: This sentence is a strong and masculine-sounding "With that being said". For this だ, see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58949/5010 It emphasizes その上, i.e., the speaker wants to emphasize he is fully aware of what he has said so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

その上 and その上で overlap, but have slight difference.

[その上](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%8A)

> さらに、一層、追加で、などといった意味の言い回し。

[その上で](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%A7)

> 既出の情報を前提して（念頭に置いて）話題を言い足す場面で接続詞的に用いられる表現。

So その上 is *in addition* and その上で is *given that/this information/situation*. The two may be interchangeable in certain cases, but in the sentence of the question, no. It means *Given that we are sorry*, or essentially *although we are sorry about that*.

だ simply ends the sentence. Just using "その上で," would sound continuing the sentence. Here "その上で、だ" can be translated as *but*, and the difference of "その上で、だ" and "その上で" may be comparable to a single emphasized *But.* and a normal *but...*. Edit: as noted by naruto in the comment, this だ can be considered as an emphasis, but the overall interpretation should be the same.

---

For example of その上で/その上:

- 彼は3年ドイツ語を勉強している。その上で今度ドイツに留学することにしたそうだ。 He's been learning German for three years. Now (with those learning as a basis) he's going to Germany for study.
- 彼は3年ドイツ語を勉強している。その上今度はフランス語の勉強を始めた。 ... Now he started to learn French (in addition).